# How to hide horizontal scrollbar and to see the whole line in the window

Tags: geany

I would like to see the whole line inside the window while using Geany, like the way Gedit handles it. I have looked through the settings, but I cannot find anything that does that. Is there something I missed in the settings, or is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this too but found no answer. And then accidentally found it in

Edit->Preferences->Various->show_editor_scrollbars

This affects both the horizontal and vertical scrollbars though.

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my problem... I was just trying to remove the scrollbars...

Answer (score 2):

**For Linux ( Ubuntu 16.04 )**

Go to `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` and add this below line to the very top-

```
horizontal.scrollbar=0
```

It'll hide your horizontal scrollbar. And don't forget to turn on wrapping line.

> Actually *Geany* is built on top of [Scintilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintilla_(software)). And this `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` file is the configuration file for [Scintilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintilla_(software)) instance used in *Geany*. Therefore we can use [this options](http://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/190/fortran/SciTEGlobal.properties) here at `geany.conf` file to modify *Geany* as we like.

I know it's kinda late, but I felt like this thing is worth sharing. So I'm hoping this will help some people.

Comment: Not late for me!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Geany's editor has a line-wrapping feature which you can set in your preferences, as described here:

- [[Geany] toggle line wrapping](http://lists.geany.org/pipermail/users/2010-September/006015.html) (mailing list)
- [Question about Line Breaking option's behaviour](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.geany.general/5882)
- [How to configure Geany to wrap lines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310312/how-to-configure-geany-to-wrap-lines) (Ask Ubuntu)

  > Go to Edit > Preferences. In the Preferences dialog, go to Editor > Features and then check the first checkbox (the one corresponding to "Line wrapping")

Comment: Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).